# Seeking Title of WWII Movie Featuring a Resistance Group and a Unique Method to Expose an Informant

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to recall the name of an old black-and-white WWII movie centered around a <s>resistance group (possibly French or Polish)</s> opposing Nazi occupation. In a pivotal scene, the group intercepts a radio (or telephone) conversation in German, leading them to suspect they have an informant in their midst. The suspect denies any knowledge of German, creating a logical conundrum: how does one debunk a claim of ignorance, especially about language proficiency?

The film elegantly portrays the challenge of refuting someone's claim of ignorance, especially in scenarios where resorting to extreme measures like torture is not an option. It's relatively straightforward to verify if someone claims to know a language, but how do you prove the opposite?

The resistance group devises a clever strategy to **elicit an involuntary response** dependent on understanding German. They devise a plan where one member tells a hilarious joke about the Führer but in German (based on the premise that the joke is truly funny only if told in German). The suspect, upon hearing the joke, cannot restrain himself and bursts into laughter, unwittingly exposing his knowledge of the language.

This scene intrigued me for its ingenuity in storytelling and its use of involuntary response as a revelation tool. Does anyone recognize this movie? Additionally, if anyone knows the German joke mentioned, I'd be very interested in hearing it. Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Unfortunately for you, this question doesn't really fit *anywhere* on Stack Exchange. Literature Stack Exchange doesn't take movie questions, Movies & TV Stack Exchange [doesn't take identification questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and you can't bypass those by going to SciFi & Fantasy Stack Exchange since the movie doesn't appear to be the correct genre.

Comment: The joke was as follows: "Wenn ist das Nunstück git und Slotermeyer? Ja! Beiherhund das Oder die Flipperwaldt gersput!"

Answer (score 1):

This sort of reminds me of the plot of *Stalag 17* (1953) except that the protagonists are prisoners of war instead of resistance.